# Filter age <30 but keep NA

Tags: r

R beginner here.
Thanks in advance for your effort in helping me.

I checked some previous questions and answers but they seem to be not quite what I am looking for.

I need to drop values of the variable 'age' <30, but leave the NA's in the ds.

Tried to fiter with dyplr:

```
DS1 <- DS  %>%
  filter(!(Age<30)
```

But it does not retain the NA's.

> Using filter_keepna() dit not work. Error message: Could not find
> function 'filter_keepna'

Any simple solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because `NA < 30` evaluates to `NA`. Also `!NA` evaluates to `NA`. Neither is `TRUE`, so `filter()` removes them. To check for `NA`, you need `is.na()`.

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
DS1 <- DS %>%
  filter(is.na(Age) | Age >= 30)  # keeps rows with NA values OR with Age not less than 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Other options with base R:

```
DS[DS$Age >= 30 | is.na(DS$Age), ]
subset(DS, Age  >= 30 | is.na(Age))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
DS1 <- DS  %>%
  filter(!(Age<30)|is.na(Age))
```

filter() only retains rows if the condition evaluates to TRUE